# PHP - array values out and get similar values

Tags: php

I have an array like this

```
Array ( [item1] => pack1 [amount1] => 1 [price1] => 25 [amount2] => 1 [price2] => 45 [item3] => pack3 [amount3] => 4 [price3] => 65 [sender] => Submit )
```

I need to get the values item1 & item3 out of the array, then remove the item on them with a

```
str_replace
```

Then find largest number with

```
max
```

just the first part that is the toughest, any ideas?

Comment: a array_search('green', $array); This doesn't grab only parts of arrays

Comment: I would encourage you to update your question with the code that you've written to this point.

Comment: Really all I need is for it to grab each of the keys that have the word "item" in them and remove Item

Comment: array_keys($_POST) to get the keys, then how would I search those returns to weed out the item1, item3?

Comment: You need to post an example of the end result, not just find this remove that.

Answer (score 0):

foreach through the array, if the key contains item then get/set the values.  Also check the value to see if it's greater than the previous to get the max

Comment: think I should use preg_match?  or what you think the best way to do that would be?

Comment: could use preg_match, or you could use stripos, if ( strpos($value, 'item') ) //set/get values

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array( "item1" => "pack1", "amount1" => 1, "price1" => 25, "amount2" => 1, "price2" => 45, "item3" => "pack3");
$b = array();
$pattern = '/item[1-9]/';
$max_index = 0;
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    if(preg_match($pattern, $key, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
        $index = str_replace("item","",$key);
        $b[$index] = $value;
        if($index > $max_index){
            $max_index = $index;
        }
    }
}
$max_value = $b[$max_index];
echo $max_value;
```